# How to set understory session

Tags: magento-enterprise, session, login, cookie

I have use Enterprice edition

**I want to set the session for magento site like Gmail.**

> The user login, the session will set.
>
> Once user click logout button the session will destory.
>
> Other wise the the session is active.
>
> If browser is closed, then again Open the browser the session should be active.
>
> if i restart the system, then again Open the magento site the session should be active.

**FYI:** Also i have tried to set cookie session time out in admin panel. But its not working when the system is restart.

Thanks for help

Comment: You can set the cookie session time like you did, and move the sessions to the database instead of files.

Comment: @Marius could you guide how can i move that

Comment: edit `app/etc/local.xml` and replace the line `<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>` with `<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>`. And clear the cache.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I haven't tested it.

Comment: @Marius It's Working for me.

Comment: Since it works, I added my comment as an answer, so this question would have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments this moving the sessions to the database seams to solve the problem.

To move the sessions to the database edit `app/etc/local.xml` and replace

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

with

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

Comment: Can you plz give some clarity on these? I browse for it. But couldn't get it. How does the session alive just changing the session save location from files to database? In this way for a guest user added product on cart will remain same over ages? Also, does it apply for CE also?