# Permanent Login until click Logout

Tags: login, logout

On Amazon, I don't have to type login ID & password info whenever I visit the amazon so I can shop instantly

but on our Magento site, customer have to login every time they visit after close the browser

Is there any way customer don't have to login even if they close browser and visit few days later until the customer click 'logout' like Amazon?

Comment: Check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/how-to-set-understory-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

> System->Configuration->Advanced->Admin->Security

and set the

> session lifetime

to how many seconds you wish.

Comment: I setup '2592000' (it's 1 month) as Session Lifetime..but it seems I have to relogin after few days? Can you let me know why it's not work for 1 month?